# What defines the runtime version of a C# proxy class generated by SVCUTIL?

Tags: c#, rest, api, svcutil.exe

I was just curious to know about what defines the runtime version of a C# proxy class generated using SVCUTIL?

```
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost 
//     if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
```

Initially I assumed it is based on the Dot net framework version later I thought it is dependent on the Visual Studio Command Prompt version but not really sure as which of these is actually responsible.

Please feel free to mark it as duplicate if other question exists on the same, I am posting because I could not find after much research! 
Thank you.

Comment: pretty sure this is simply "what version of svcutil are you running?", which depends *mostly* on your `PATH` environment variable; i.e. run `where svcutil` at the command-line to see where it is coming from; an IDE could choose to execute a *specific* version tied to the IDE location / version, rather than just using the command-line, of course - and note that several command-line tools are really just proxies to functionality delivered in GAC'd assemblies, so ... then it depends on what is in the GAC :)

Comment: Not the svcutil version, it is what you get out of Environment.Version.  Revision 42000 is .NET 4.6 or later.  Why this is useful is not so obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @MarcGravell and HansPassant. I don't know for sure and even I was guessing some things but is it possible that we reach one concrete conclusion over this based on some documentation?